# PHP security: How to secure emailed link with get variable?

Tags: php, security, email, variables, get

I have a link that's emailed to the user:

e.g. `http://somesite/path/page.php?hash=19a893775098b441b8b088387c19fccce2a1fce3`

This link is emailed to a user and this unique hash is validated against a database via PHP. This is using proper prepared queries so that injections cannot be performed. This link also isn't visible anywhere in the site and expires after a month. If the hash fails validation, the page results in a `401 Unauthorized`

When the user visits the link he would be able to type in a reply (that saves into the DB). Ideally, I'd also want to show some (possibly) semi-sensitive data inside the link. Would that be a good idea? How can I further secure an emailed link like this?

Comment: If the user is registered i'd also add an user id to the url. But i think is not a good idea to add sensitive data to an url query since a lot of people uses free WIFIS without protection etc... and is easy to catch url/passwords using some sniffing software.

Comment: How does this "secure" a link? Everyone who reads the email can use the link. What you are refering to is generally known as a "token". Try google for solutions.

Comment: @DBPBTPV what if I just allow a reply (DB save) without displaying sensitive data? But if I add also a user id, then it'll just be another get variable in the url

Comment: @arkascha I want to secure the link. Yes, whoever reads the email should be okay to access the link since it's a server generated email to just one email address. That hash is generated for this one email

Comment: @Benjamin Well, yes, so your link is as secure as the person's email, which is, in general "not very", especially while it's in transit. If there's sensitive information, or repercussions to someone other than the recipient "replying", I'd still require proper authentication first. It's a judgement call, in the end. (Would it help to add warnings to the page to discourage fraud? "You are posting as an unauthenticated user from IP address x.x.x.x...", etc.)

Comment: Please note that email is not a secure medium to exchange information. Reading emails addressed at someone else is surprising simple in many cases. So there is no secrecy hiding an url inside an email message. Consider it public posted.

Comment: @MattGibson & Arkascha. Hmm, good point about the email itself not being that secure.

Answer (score 0):

I guess all these hashes are associated with the appropriate users in your database. So, when opening the link, you may authenticate the user (request his/her password) to extend security.

Comment: That's a good measure. But unnecessary if the data isn't very sensitive and the link doesn't exist anywhere else.

Comment: The hash is not associated to the user, but to the message that can be replied to in the link. The person given the link doesn't actually have credentials to the site, so I can't check it. It's like giving another person a temporary access to visit the secret link